# how to install ethereum in raspbian?

Tags: ethgasstation

http://raspnode.com/diyEthereumGeth.html#installethereum

recipe for target 'geth' failed
make: *** [geth] Error 2

please provide me the solution ?

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: ethereum run sucessfully but how to build peer to peer connection in different devices?

Comment: The 5-6 lines before `make: ***` would be important to include. Make doesn't know what failed, it just knows that something didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to run geth on Raspberry Pi under Raspbian. The easiest way is to download the corresponding Linux ARM binary from https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/